# How can I work around a locked down desktop image in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, desktop-customization

My work PC has a fixed desktop image which is automatically pulled from the server when I log in. My user account does not have administrative privileges, and desktop image settings have been locked out. The image is hideous (all one shade, low resolution, and stretched to "fit" my widescreen monitor) and I would *really* like to get rid of it. Can it be done?

Here are some details:

- The image is automatically loaded into a directory on my PC whenever I log in at the beginning of the day, and whenever I lock/unlock the computer (many times per day)
- I have full read & write access to the directory that contains the desktop image
- If I replace the image file and then refresh my desktop (F5) the new image will appear. This is good, but the old image will be back the next time I log in or unlock the computer

Note: I am not interested in doing anything which will compromise the company security system. I just want to change the local desktop image within the restrictions that have been imposed. The fact that I have write access to the image makes me think that it can be done without too much hassle, I just don't know the best way to go about it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Are you allowed to run batch files in your environment ? If so, you could write a simple bat-file that overwrites the image.

Now the tricky part is to run the batch file automatically every time you login or unlock the computer. It really depends on how much rights you have on the system. If you can create scheduled tasks as well, I think you can create a task that starts the batch file every time you login under Accessories -> System Tools -> Scheduled Tasks. This should then include unlocking.

Maybe a start!?

Comment: That certainly worked for login, which is awesome, but it doesn't work for unlock.

Comment: I guess one way would be to write a package that subscribes to windows events as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270629/run-a-script-when-either-locking-or-unlocking-windows-xp. But this gets kind of ugly ;-) Not to mention the security question again..

Answer (score 1):

This might not work, but its worth a shot. I do this at my school all the time. Open firefox, select an image and right click and "Set as Desktop background".

Answer (score -1):

To change a desktop background install this program from this link: www.bionixwallpaper.com/ and then load up the exe file that it downloads.

It shouldn't require any admin access to load up and then choose a accessable hard disc such as a thumbdrive or a network drive that you can access to install the program on.

1. Once you install it, find the exe file in the folder that it installed in called "Bionix Wallpaper.exe" and run that.
2. Then, you want to select all of the images in the list and delete all of them.
3. Click the 4th button on the tool-bar and select what you would like to be your desktop picture
4. Click the "down arrow" button on the top menu.
5. Go to your desktop and you should see that your desktop background has changed.

Your desktop background has now been secretly changed without admin access.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.